# sync text-box to combo-box

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Created combo-box to view suppliers, sync'd it to another combo-box displaying all products(Product_Name) for that company

I need the Product_Code for the Product_Name(that was selected)(same table),
in a text-box in the same form

IE..Products combo-box
I have to view Products by name and once selected the closed combo-box must display the Product_Name, So I can not save the Product_Code,when using the wizard.

How do i sync the text-box to display the product_code, of the Product that was selected in the combo-box

I did get it to work when product_code and product_name is view'd in combo-box but then in the wizard of it I selected to save Product_Code .. ie. so once selected only the code shows and not the name

Comment: I got it to work, Thanks for the view though...
simple bound column and width property.....
just needed a break to see the solution, i suppose.
THANKS... sorry about that

Comment: Why did you post the question twice? -1